# How to chop off characters after a space?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable - 2 words separated by a single space : $var = "xxxx yyyy". In perl, how do i use regular expressions to make $var = "xxxx"

Thanks,
Trinity

Comment: Thanks everyone, perl is true to its word - there's more than one way to do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `\s.+$` by nothing:

```
$var =~ s/ .+$//
```

(as per elusive's comment)

Comment: @elusive: I have no clue. I've never used Perl :-). I've seen `=~` used for matching, maybe it works for substitution as well, but Perl is so syntax-heavy that I really don't know.

Comment: @elusive Right you are. But why add the 'g'; 'global up to the end'?

Comment: @canavanin: It is just a habit. You need `g` almost always.

Answer (score 2):

You don't!
Okay, you could, but why?

```
substr $var, index($var, ' '), length $var, '';
```

It's not quite a premature optimization, but more of an "avoiding the golden hammer" situation.

Comment: Or just `substr($var, index($var, ' ')) = "";`

Comment: ++ for using substr as an lvalue!

Comment: Cute, I think it's been ages I used something like that and that was in VB 6 with `Mid$` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = (split / /, $var, 2)[0];
```

Or

```
($var) = $var =~ /^(\S+)/;
```